# Get all child elements including body using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

The code below gets all children within `body` but it does not get the `body` element itself. How can I get all child elements including `body` with pure JavaScipt?

```
document.querySelectorAll('body *');
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('*');`

Comment: I dont want everything I just want all elements within body including body tag.

Comment: `document.children[0].children[1]`

Comment: @2619 : `document.querySelectorAll('body,body *');`

Comment: Do you mean children or descendants?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting all inner elements of `body` tag instead use `*` to get all elements.

```
document.querySelectorAll('*');
```

---

If you want to get `body` and its all inner elements then use [comma separated multiple selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors#Selector_lists).

```
document.querySelectorAll('body,body *');
```